# C++ pointer runtime error

Tags: c++, pointers, for-loop, runtime-error

I made a program using structure and pointer. But for some reason it is not working properly. The main problem is that, for-loop would no go as it would. It would be helpful if you could solve this problem

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

struct Book{
    string name;
    int release;
};

int main(){
    //local variable
    int i;
    string release_dte;
    int choice;
    //interface
    cout << "Welcome to Book Storage CPP" << endl;
    cout << "How many entries would you like to make: ";
    cin >> choice;
    Book* Issue = new Book[choice];
    //for handler
    for (i = 0; i < choice; i++){
        cout << "Book: ";
        getline(cin, Issue[i].name);
        cout << "Release Date: ";
        getline(cin, release_dte);
        Issue[i].release = atoi(release_dte.c_str());
    }
    cout << "These are your books" << endl;
    for ( i = 0; i < choice; i++){
        cout << "Book: " << Issue[i].name << " Release Date: " << Issue[i].release << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What exactly fails? What do you see, what do you expect? Compile the program with all warnings (and optimization, the compiler might notice some problems only while doing the analysis for optimization). There just isn't a way around *you* learning to find out what goes on here.

Comment: Basically, when this program get to for-loop. It skips over the first input and goes to the second one.

Comment: That's because you still have a newline stuck in the beginning of the stream. `std::getline()` stops when it hits a newline, that's why the input isn't being attempted.

Comment: @user3264250, see my answer down, you have to add a cin.ignore() to avoid the new line issue between the two getline() functions

Comment: @0x499602D2 if you don't mind, can you tell me in detail of what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not checking if the input succeeded, nor are you clearing the new line left after the extraction into `choice`:

> ```
> if ((std::cout << "Book: "),
>         std::getline(std::cin >> std::ws, Input[i].name) &&
>     (std::cout << "Release Date: "),
>         std::getline(std::cin >> std::ws, release_dte))
> {
>     Input[i].release = std::stoi(release_dte);
> }
> ```

You should also be using `std::stoi` for C++ strings as shown above.

Comment: Note that `std::stoi` is only available since C++11.

Comment: Just few question I would like you to answer since I am just a beginner 1)Why would you put if statement 2) what does std::ws means 3)Can you kindly explain me what is happening here, in easy terms would be nice

Comment: @user3264250 1) `std::getline()` returns `std::cin`. When we put it in the context of an `if` statement, it will return `true` if the extraction was succesful, or `false` if the extraction failed. 2) `std::ws` is a manipulator that extracts and discards leading whitespace from the stream. Whitespace is considered by the stream to be the space character, the newline character, and some others. It will stop when it reaches the end of the stream or when it finds a non-whitespace character. I will answer question 3 in my next comment...

Comment: @user3264250 3) When you did `cin >> choice`, you entered the number and you also pressed `Enter` which left the newline character in the stream. `std::getline()` stops extracting input when it finds a newline character. If the first character is a newline, the input cannot be performed. That's why you are experiencing that "skipping" behavior. The second call to `std::getline()` works because when `std::getline()` discovers a newline character, it stops the input and then discards the newline character. That's why you have to discard the leading whitespace before `std::getline()` begins.

Comment: @user3264250 If you have any more questions or concerns, just ask here and I will try my best to explain it to you.

Comment: @0x499602D2 I did understood what you said and there is one more thing I would like to ask you. The post below your by H N suggested that putting cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); would fix the skipping and it did. So I was just curious, whats the big difference in his line of code and yours. Thank you for your response for the previous answer.

Comment: @user3264250 The difference is that `ignore(n, c)` indiscriminately discards characters until it either discards `n` characters, finds the delimiter (specified by the second argument `c`) or hits the end of the stream. `std::ws` only discards whitespace until it hits a non-whitespace character or the end of the stream. Functionally, there is no difference because the only thing left in the stream after `cin >> choice` is a newline (assuming you entered only an integer). If you entered something like a string, then the `ignore()` would be necessary to discard that invalid input.

Answer (score 2):

I could not exactly infer  what is the problem you are referring to. But my guess is getline() function inside the for loop is not working properly, I suggest the code before the for loop to be like the following\

```
cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

for (i = 0; i < choice; i++){
    cout << "Book: ";
    getline(cin, Issue[i].name);
    cout << "Release Date: ";
    getline(cin, release_dte);
    Issue[i].release = atoi(release_dte.c_str());
}
```

Your final code should be

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

struct Book{
  string name;
  int release;
};

int main(){
//local variable
int i;
string release_dte;
int choice;
//interface
cout << "Welcome to Book Storage CPP" << endl;
cout << "How many entries would you like to make: ";
cin >> choice;
Book* Issue = new Book[choice];

cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

//for handler
for (i = 0; i < choice; i++){
    cout << "Book: ";
    getline(cin, Issue[i].name);
    cout << "Release Date: ";
    getline(cin, release_dte);
    Issue[i].release = atoi(release_dte.c_str());
}
cout << "These are your books" << endl;
for ( i = 0; i < choice; i++){
    cout << "Book: " << Issue[i].name << " Release Date: " << Issue[i].release << endl;
}
system("pause");
return 0;
```

}

This will work as you intended

Comment: Well it did gave me the chance to input but when it come to display, It displays everything but not the first book input as in              Welcome to Book Storage cpp                                            How many entries would you like to make: 1                                   Book: Blah                                                                   Release Date: 1999                                                                Book: Release Date:1999

Comment: add this cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); before the for loop as well, then it works fine

Comment: Well I did like your method and worked fine but there is a huge gap between Book and Release Date. Why is that?

Comment: actually this line 
cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

should come before the for loop not inside the loop, then it works fine, i have edited my answer, see that